# Heroku, Play Framework, Phantomjs

Tags: heroku, playframework-2.0, phantomjs

I have a play 2 framework app runnning in heroku. How do I add phantomjs support to the play 2 app?

I know a builspack exists for heroku for phantomjs. How do I specifically add this to my existing play 2 app?

Comment: How is PhantomJS normally added to a Play 2 app?  Is this just a binary you need on the system?

Comment: Hi James, this is probably the way to go although I have no experience on doing this. I will research a bit more. BY the way James thanks for your excellent tutorials on heroku and the play framework on your blog. they have been very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is the only way, but it works for us

- install phantomjs in your machine
- in your build.sbt libraryDependencies add `"com.github.detro.ghostdriver" % "phantomjsdriver" % "1.1.0" % "test",`
- in your test `WithBrowser(webDriver = classOf[org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver])`